# Add explanation to equation

Tags: equations, environments

I want to add equation in which there is an explanation of what means the symbols used in the equation. So far, I  have this

[image]

And I want to have somethihg like this:

[image]

Can anyone help me, please?

My MWE is:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
Umsatz = V_{R} \times R_{Zeit} \times R_{Konz} \times \dot{c}
\end{equation}

With

\begin{table}[h!]
\begin{tabular}{cc}
Umsatz & total mass flow converted during the reaction in {kmol/h} \\
$V_{R}$ & Catalyst volume in $m^{3}$
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Off topic : never use ``table`` wan you do't need a float !
``tabular`` or  ``tabularx``, or the alignments structures of amsmath/mathtools (as shown below) will do the job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible solution with `alignat` and`fleqn` from `nccmath`: which places  equation environments at the left margin (with a cusstomisable distance from the left margin). I took the liberty to replace ‘with’ by ‘where’, which is better style. Also units are not typed in italic; to have a correct formatting of units, use the `siunitx` package:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}
\usepackage{siunitx} 

\begin{document}

\begin{fleqn}
   \begin{alignat}{2}
     & \text{Kinetic } & \quad & \mathit{Umsatz} = V_{R} \cdot R_\text{Zeit} \cdot R_\text{Konz} \cdot \dot{c} \\[1.5ex]
     & \text{where} & &
    \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}r <{:}@{\space}l}
    $ \mathit{Umsatz} $ & total mass flow converted during the reaction in \si{kmol/h} \\
    $V_{R}$ & Catalyst volume in \si{m^{3}}
    \end{tabular} \notag
    \end{alignat}
\end{fleqn}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `:\,\space` seems like overkill and also the extra space in `\text{Kinetic }`. On another note, despite that `_\text{...}` works, I thought we should encourage users to write `_{\text{...}}`. ;-) Also, why not use `\cdot` instead of `\times` as shown in the picture from the OP?

Comment: You're right, I removed `\,`. As to `\times` I guess I was looking at the other picture. 'Tis fixed. Thank you for pointing these inconsistencies!

Comment: Thanks! It worked! iIs there any way to add a line break without adding to the second line the ":" at the beginning?

Comment: I'm not too sure exactly what you're referring to. Do you mean you'd like to have ‘*Umsatz:*’  with a colon and ‘$V_R$’ without?